# MySQL Query - getting missing records when using group-by

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I have a query :

> ```
> select score, count(1) as 'NumStudents' from testresults where testid = 'mytestid'
> group by score order by score
> ```

where testresults table contains the performances of students in a test. A sample result looks like the following, assuming maximum marks of the test is 10.

> **score, NumStudents**
>
> 0 10 
>  1 20 
>  2 12 
>  3 5 
>  5 34 
>  .. 
>  10 23

As you can see, this query does not return any records for scores which no student have scored. For eg. nobody scored 4/10 in the test and there are no records for score = 4 in the query output.

I would like to change the query so that I can get these missing records with 0 as the value for the NumStudents field. So that my end output would have max + 1 records, one for each possible score.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

The database contains several tests and the maximum marks for the test is part of the test definition. So having a new table for storing all possible scores is not feasible. In the sense that whenever I create a new test with a new max marks, I need to ensure that the new table should be changed to contain these scores as well.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is good at working with sets of data values in the database, but not so good at sets of data values that are *not* in the database.

The best workaround is to keep one small table for the values you need to range over:

```
CREATE TABLE ScoreValues (score int);
INSERT INTO ScoreValues (score) 
  VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

Given your comment that you define the max marks of a test in another table, you can join to that table in the following way, as long as `ScoreValues` is sure to have values at least as high or higher than the greatest test's max marks:

```
SELECT v.score, COUNT(tr.score) AS 'NumStudents'
FROM ScoreValues v 
  JOIN Tests t ON (v.score <= t.maxmarks)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TestResults tr ON (v.score = tr.score AND t.testid = tr.testid)
WHERE t.testid = 'mytestid'
GROUP BY v.score;
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way would be to create a table named "Scores" and left outer join your table to it.

SELECT s.score, COUNT(1) AS scoreCount
FROM score AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN testScores AS ts
ON s.score = ts.score
GROUP BY s.score

If you don't want to create the table, you could use

SELECT
  1 as score, SUM(CASE WHEN ts.score = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS scoreCount,
  2 as score, SUM(CASE WHEN ts.score = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS scoreCount,
  3 as score, SUM(CASE WHEN ts.score = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS scoreCount,
  4 as score, SUM(CASE WHEN ts.score = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS scoreCount,
  ...
  10 as score, SUM(CASE WHEN ts.score = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS scoreCount
FROM testScores AS ts

Comment: @le dorfier: Ya, generally that would work. In my specific case though, the maximum marks of a test is part of the test definition and when there are loads of tests with different maxmarks, having a table to store all the possible scores is not feasible.

Comment: You'd best document the problem more completely then. It's hard to imagine a real situation where the range of possible scores is beyond the capacity of a bespoke table.

Answer (score 0):

Does MySQL support set-returning functions?  Recent releases of PostgreSQL have a function, `generate_series(start, stop)` that produces the value `start` on the first row, `start+1` on the second, and so on up to `stop` on the `stop`th row.  The advantage of this is that you can put this function in a subselect in the `FROM` clause and then join to it, instead of creating and populating a table and joining to that as suggested by le dorfier and Bill Karwin.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support that kind of function.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a mental exercise I came up with this to generate a sequence in MySQL. As long as the number of tables in all databases on the box squared are less than the total length of the sequence it will work. I wouldn't recommend it for production though ;)

```
SELECT @n:=@n+1 as n from (select @n:=-1) x, Information_Schema.Tables y, Information_Schema.Tables WHERE @n<20; /* sequence from 0 to 20 inclusive */
```