# Query sum speedup - Date series for charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, series

The following query runs fairly quickly, but the series processing that needs to take place afterwards is really slowing this method down. I could use some help in refactoring.

```
def self.sum_amount_chart_series(start_time)
  orders_by_day = Widget.archived.not_void.
                  where(:print_datetime => start_time.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).
                  group(pg_print_date_group).
                  select("#{pg_print_date_group} as print_date, sum(amount) as total_amount")


  # THIS IS WHAT IS SLOWING THE METHOD DOWN!
  (start_time.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
    order = orders_by_day.detect { |order| order.print_date.to_date == date }
    order && order.total_amount.to_f.round(2) || 0.0
  end

end

def self.pg_print_date_group
  "CAST((print_datetime + interval '#{tz_offset_hours} hours') AS date)"
end
```

I have benchmarked this method and the offending code is the series loop where it generates a series of dates and then maps out a new array with an amount for each date. This way I get a series back with amounts for every date, regardless if it has an amount or not.

When the query only returns a few dates, it runs fairly quickly. But set the start date back a year or two and it becomes impossibly slow. The real offender is the *.detect* method. It's very slow at scanning the array of activerecord objects.

Is there a faster method to generates this series?

Comment: Have you tried doing the SQL query inside the date loop (just grab the order by the date supplied, and if nil, return 0.0)? It may be faster to let MySQL do all the lookups for you, instead of trying to get Ruby to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434571/mysql-query-getting-missing-records-when-using-group-by - Some answers can point you to make the query change to include all dates and avoid using detect.

Comment: @Vijay: I did try that. Since I'm using Postgres, I tried incorporating a RIGHT JOIN with generate_series, but I was never able to get it to work correctly (it left out the dates with 0.0 amount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orders_by_day is grouped by "pg_print_date_group" so it should be a hash of "date" to objects. so why don't you just do

```
(start_time.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
  order = orders_by_day[date.to_s(:db)]
  order && order.total_amount.to_f.round(2) || 0.0
end
```

That should seriously reduce the Big O of your run. And if I'm misunderstanding and your orders_by_day isn't a hash, preprocess it into a hash and then run the map, you definitely don't want to detect for every date.

Comment: you led me to... 'orders_by_day.index_by(&:print_date)' which creates a hash out of the AR array using the print_date, then I can access the amount using the resulting hash. MUCHO faster!

Answer (score 0):

Since the primary offender in your code is the detect method that has to scan the array again and again, I suggest that you invert the order in which you create the series, so that you only scan the array once, and your code runs in O(n) time.

Try something along the lines of:

```
series = []
next_date = start_time.to_date
orders_by_day.each do |order|
  while order.print_date.to_date < next_date
    series <<  0.0
    next_date = next_date.next
  end
  series << order.total_amount.to_f.round(2)
  next_date += 1
end
while next_date < Date.today
    series <<  0.0
    next_date = next_date.next
end
```

Please note that my code is untested ;)